Algorithm for insetting boundary edges on a 3D polygon mesh
I have a polygon soup mesh (ie one without clear structure), and am wanting to inset the edges into the polygon, correctly handling holes, tight corners etc.
Eg given the mesh:

I want to be able to generate contours like so:

I've had a look into a couple of of contour parallel toolpath generation techniques, but most of those assume 2D polygons defined by a single boundary edge. Even the ones that handle 3D cases seem to flatten it into a 2D space, which I'm not sure will work for very convex shapes.
So:
Given an arbitrary 3D polygon mesh with boundary/open edges, how can I generate contours/inset from the edges?

Seems to not have received much visibility. Is there any more detail I should add to this question? Is there a more suitable site on the stackexchange network?

Unfortunately I don't have the answer right at hand nor the time, hennce just a comment I hope can help with a direction. Would a geometric processing library (with relevant algorithms) be of help ? For example CGAL or libigl: these are c++, but should have Python bindings as well. Once you find a suitable algorithm/lib/ double check licensing based on your needs as well. HTH

I'm already using some geometry libraries, namely trimesh and manifold3d, but AFAIK no geometry library seems to offer this operation out of the box.

This problem appears to be known as 'geodesics' and there are some solutions in research papers such as "Geodesics in heat: a new approach to computing distance based on heat flow"

Just a comment:

I'd look into Matlab "3D" contour source code. (Don't have Matlab on my PC. I believe if you'd install it, you must have access to their source code and see how their 3-D contour's been implemented. )

NIST defines contour as a plot, that "is a graphical technique for representing a 3-dimensional surface by plotting constant z slices, called contours, on a 2-dimensional format. That is, given a value for z, lines are drawn for connecting the (x,y) coordinates where that z value occurs."

I tried looking into Graham's scan, but it does not look that simple.   We should first define the surfaces and clearly define one or several 2-d planes for "where that z value occurs" in order to scale any algorithm from 2-d to 3-d for plotting a contour.

Here is a failed attempt of using Graham's scan in 3-D. Might give you some clues:


Random 3-d points:
This O(N^3) part simply generates some random points (technically your input points).
random.seed(0) ## This keeps the randomness consistent. 
A = []
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        for k in range(8):
            A.append((random.randint(1, 25), random.randint(50, 75), random.randint(26, 45)))


Running Graham's Scan:

Imagine you got 1000 points

First remove the duplicate points (if any, let's assume we have 0 duplicate points here.)

Run Graham's Scan

Let's say you get 80 points the first convex hull ("contour").

Add those points in a visited set

Now we have 1000 - 80 = 920 points


Repeat the above steps until you would reach a few points. Each repeat finds a new convex hull.
From the Wikipedia (Graham's Scan)

contour = []

while len(set(A)) > 2:
    A = list(set(A))
    convex_hull_3d = graham_3d(A)
    contour.append(convex_hull_3d)
    A = list(set(A) - set(convex_hull_3d)) ## Here I'm just removing the convex hull points from the initial points (i.e., A) 


Code
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


def orient_3d(p, q, r):
    val = (q[1] - p[1]) * ((r[0] - p[0]) * (q[2] - p[2]) - (r[2] - p[2]) * (q[0] - p[0])) - \
        (q[0] - p[0]) * ((r[1] - p[1]) * (q[2] - p[2]) - (r[2] - p[2]) * (q[1] - p[1]))
    if val == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 if val > 0 else 2


def graham_3d(points):
    if len(points) < 3:
        return []

    SPS = sorted(points, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0], x[2]))
    SPS = SPS[:1] + sorted(SPS[1:], key=lambda x: (x[1] - SPS[0][1]) / (
        x[0] - SPS[0][0]) if (x[0] - SPS[0][0]) != 0 else float('inf'))

    stack = [SPS[0], SPS[1], SPS[2]]
    for i in range(3, len(SPS)):
        while len(stack) > 1 and orient_3d(stack[-2], stack[-1], SPS[i]) != 2:
            stack.pop()
        stack.append(SPS[i])

    return stack


random.seed(0)
A = []
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        for k in range(8):
            A.append((random.randint(1, 25), random.randint(50, 75), random.randint(26, 45)))


contour = []

while len(set(A)) > 2:
    A = list(set(A))
    convex_hull_3d = graham_3d(A)
    contour.append(convex_hull_3d)
    A = list(set(A) - set(convex_hull_3d))

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot each convex hull
for convex_hull in contour:
    convex_hull.append(convex_hull[0])
    x, y, z = zip(*convex_hull)
    ax.plot(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()




The above randomly plotted Graham's scan does not consider any 2-D plane to revolve the contour around. These images show how it looks:



Image 1
Image 2
How Graham's Scan works:

Precision
If you're concerned about accuracy and precision, then Graham's algo is a good start point. Otherwise, if you just want some level of approximated contours on your data points, there are other approaches.
Time Complexity

O(N (log N) ^ 2)


For contours parallel to the surface boundaries
I'd look into:

Proximity maps (See here)
Kernel density estimation

KDE
# 2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

# Generate random points
points = np.random.randn(500, 2)

# Fit KDE
kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=1.5, metric='euclidean')
kde.fit(points)

# Generate grid of points to evaluate KDE
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 100), np.linspace(-3, 3, 100))
xy = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()]).T
z = np.exp(kde.score_samples(xy))
z = z.reshape(x.shape)


plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='Greens')
plt.colorbar(label='Density')
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s=5, color='black', alpha=0.8)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Kernel Density Estimation (KDE)')
plt.show()




This work builds surfaces from contours using graphs, ancient but still interesting.


Hey1, thanks for your response. Matlab's contour plot plots lines equidistantly spaced on the Z axis, which is a bit different about what I am seeking to achieve. I call these sets of lines "contours" because it appears to be what they are called in literature about "contour-parallel toolpaths" which appear to me to be pretty similar. They are different to contours as you would find on a map.

I've had a bit of a skim about Grahams Scan, and I'm not sure quite what you are trying to achieve with your code. Can you explain your algorithm a bit more? Even if it doesn't work quite how you planned, I am still interested in knowing your thought process here.

@sdfgeoff Added brief explanations. Do you now understand how it works?

Ahh, so you're trying to find the outer contours by finding the outermost set of points each iteration. I think this method would work given a convex surface and equidistant vertices. Not sure it generalizes to quite what I am trying to do (as for my intended use requires contours parallel to the surface boundaries), but still a very interesting method. Thanks for the idea and explanation.

@sdfgeoff Exactly!

This reminds me of a function I needed a few years back for superimposed meshes: How to associate small cells from one mesh to a bigger cell from the other mesh, based on position. I ended up running a brute force algorithm to do so.
In your case, assuming you have identified your outer edges, you could add more points on them, to improve the precision of your contours. Then apply a refined mesh on top of your inner mesh: random or not, your choice.
Then run an algorithm like this:
for loop on inner_points
    initialise distance to infinity
    for loop on outer_points
        evaluate new_distance between inner_point and outer_point
        if new_distance < distance
            distance = new_distance
        end if
    end for loop
    assign distance to this inner point
end for loop

draw distance scalar field

This is not the cleanest solution, but that should work nonetheless.
However, if your mesh is completely folded, you might encounter issues with this algorithm, that does not take into account the distance "on the surface". That would require a bit more work.

Yeah, if you can obtain a mesh where each vertex is a known distance from the border then this becomes a solvable problem. And yeah, finding that is hard. Finding the border edges is simple (edges with num_faces = 1), and I quite like your algorithm for finding distance to edge. I think it would work given a highly regular mesh, and get less accurate the more degenerate. If you move points between the inner and outer sets I think it can be made more accurate even if the mesh is folded (ie should use distance based on neighbours rather than only to outer points).

Using only the distance = distance between point and neighbour + distance between neighbour and edge could lead to weird results, due to the probable angle between these two segments. That small error would increase the farther away one point is from the outer edge.

maybe a structure like half-edge / winged mesh can help traverse data (find edge loops) ?

I've awarded you the bounty! This isn't a complete solution, but it will work for simple, relatively flat meshes with high vertex density.
I recently found that there do appear to be exact solutions in research papers (Eg "Accurate Computation of Geodesic Distance Fields for Polygonal Curves on Triangle Meshes"), but not implementations that I could find.

Thank you sdfgeoff, it's a complex topic with still ongoing research being done. I hope you find a proper algorithm some day!
